How to create a custom SSD object detection model using pre-trained image classification models from tensorflow?
I am currently working on a project where I want to create a custom SSD object detection model on google colab, but I want to use an InceptionNet and ResNet50 for the "backbone"/feature-extractor. These two models will be connected to become a hybrid model (output concatenation). The part where I am stuck right now is what loss function to use from the keras library, or if I need to develop my own loss function. In addition to this, I am also confused on what metric I need to use for evaluation. All the resources I have found so far are creating models from scratch, and I would like to avoid this by using the tools available in keras.
This is the model I have created so far (ignore the loss function), and I am aware I need to add multiple convolutional layers still to actually make the predictions.

I apologize if this question comes off as confusing or even impossible to solve. I am new to image classification and object detection in general. If possible, I would prefer if the solution is simple so it is easy for me to grasp.

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask
